# How to use the aria combobox role with a grid element?

Tags: combobox, accessibility, wai-aria, wcag

I'm trying to make an accessible calendar plugin where you can write the date in the input by hand or select it from a table. I'm using WAI-ARIA and I think I'm following the instructions correctly but the Chrome Developer Tools Accessibility audit gives me an error seen below

Instructions:

https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#combobox

https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#grid

Example:

https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices-1.1/examples/combobox/aria1.1pattern/grid-combo.html

Error:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OIX1f.png

My code:

```
<div class="container">
    <label for="comboboxtextbox">the label</label>
    <div role="combobox" aria-expanded="true" aria-owns="comboboxgrid" aria-haspopup="grid">
        <input role="textbox" aria-multiline="false" id="comboboxtextbox" type="text" aria-controls="comboboxgrid">
    </div>
    <table role="grid" id="comboboxgrid">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>one</th>
                <th>two</th>
                <th>three</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td role="gridcell">1</td>
                <td role="gridcell">2</td>
                <td role="gridcell">3</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message is saying that anything with a role of combobox has required child elements but it can’t find them in your markup. There’s been [some changes to the combobox role](https://www.levelaccess.com/differences-aria-1-0-1-1-changes-rolecombobox/) so if you’re working from an older example it’ll be out of date. Try removing the role attributes from both the div and the table, and see if that helps.

Comment: If I remove the role attributes there will be no errors because there will be nothing to validate ;) Unfortunately I have this problem in version 1.1 and there aren't any real examples out there. This is the only one I could find, it's an official example and as far as I see... it has the same error.

Comment: Going by that example then, you need to add role="row" as well as role="gridcell" to your table.